# Python - ffill() with subtraction

Tags: python, pandas, ffill

I'm trying to fill NAs by using the previous Total and then subtracting the Change

```
            Change Total
01/01/2021  -12 100
02/01/2021  -54 154
03/01/2021  -23 177
04/01/2021  -2  NaN
05/01/2021  -54 NaN
06/01/2021  -72 NaN
```

Desired output;

```
            Change Total
01/01/2021  -12 100
02/01/2021  -54 154
03/01/2021  -23 177
04/01/2021  -2  179
05/01/2021  -54 233
06/01/2021  -72 305
```

I've attempted various ways of manipulating the ffill() but with no success;

```
df['Total'] = df['Total'].fillna(method = 'ffill' - df['Change'])
```

Is there a better way to attempt this?
Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected output looks like [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) minus [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html). Forward fill the last valid value then subtract the cumulative total at each NaN row:

```
# Select NaN rows
m = df['Total'].isna()
# Update NaN rows with the last valid value minus the current total Change
df.loc[m, 'Total'] = df['Total'].ffill() - df.loc[m, 'Change'].cumsum()
```

`df`:

```
            Change  Total
01/01/2021     -12  100.0
02/01/2021     -54  154.0
03/01/2021     -23  177.0
04/01/2021      -2  179.0
05/01/2021     -54  233.0
06/01/2021     -72  305.0
```

Comment: Good observation +1

Comment: ++vNice one :-) .

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.Series.where`:

```
df["Total"] = df["Total"].where(df["Total"].notnull(),
                                df['Total'].ffill() - df.loc[df['Total'].isnull(), 'Change'].cumsum())

print (df)

            Change  Total
01/01/2021     -12  100.0
02/01/2021     -54  154.0
03/01/2021     -23  177.0
04/01/2021      -2  179.0
05/01/2021     -54  233.0
06/01/2021     -72  305.0
```

Comment: Kindly check your output

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `combine_first`

```
df = df.combine_first(df[['Total']].ffill().sub(df.loc[df.Total.isnull(),'Change'].cumsum(),axis=0))
df
            Change  Total
01/01/2021     -12  100.0
02/01/2021     -54  154.0
03/01/2021     -23  177.0
04/01/2021      -2  179.0
05/01/2021     -54  233.0
06/01/2021     -72  305.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` and `fillna()` as follows: :

```
change_when_total_null = df.loc[df['Total'].isnull(), 'Change']
df['Total'] = np.where(df['Total'].isnull(),df['Total'].fillna(method='ffill') -change_when_total_null.cumsum(),df['Total'])
```

prints:

```
            Change  Total
01/01/2021     -12  100.0
02/01/2021     -54  154.0
03/01/2021     -23  177.0
04/01/2021      -2  179.0
05/01/2021     -54  233.0
06/01/2021     -72  305.0
```

Comment: Kindly check your output –

Comment: Thank you @BENY. Updated. Was in a hurry when I did this